# Threads are not getting terminatedl; stuck in loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I have 4 threads each one is executing different method, I'm able to pull the desire output however the threads are not getting terminated or not able to get out of the loop when the job has finished.

Could someone help me with your opinion.

I think each thread has stuck on await statement and expecting someone to signal it. I tried explicitly signalling all threads after task has been done but no luck.

When one thread signals other doesn't the executing threads recheck the condition of a while loop, since I'm setting the flag to false but it doesn't have any effect.

```
    private int n;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition executeFizz;
    Condition executeBuzz;
    Condition executeFizzBuzz;
    Condition executeNumber;
    volatile private boolean flag;   

    public FizzyBuzz(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.executeFizz = lock.newCondition();
        this.executeBuzz = lock.newCondition();
        this.executeFizzBuzz = lock.newCondition();
        this.executeNumber = lock.newCondition();
        this.flag = true;
    }

    public  void fizz()   {
        lock.lock();
        while(true) {
        try {           
            executeFizz.await();
            if(!flag) break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("fizz");
        executeNumber.signal();
        }

    }

    public void buzz()  {
        lock.lock();
        while(true) {
        try {
            executeBuzz.await();
            if(!flag) break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("buzz");
        executeNumber.signal();

        }

    }

    public void fizzbuzz()   {
        lock.lock();
        while(true) {
        try {
            executeFizzBuzz.await();
            if(!flag) break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("fizzbuzz");
        executeNumber.signal();
        }

    }

    public  void number() throws InterruptedException  {
        lock.lock();
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {       
            if(i%3==0&&i%5==0)
                {
                    executeFizzBuzz.signal();
                    executeNumber.await();
                }
            else if(i%3==0)
                {

                    executeFizz.signal();
                    executeNumber.await();
                }
                else if(i%5==0)
                {
                    executeBuzz.signal();
                    executeNumber.await();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }   
        }
        flag = false;
        executeFizzBuzz.signal();
        executeFizz.signal();
        executeBuzz.signal();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this doesn't do what you were thinking it does:

```
while (flag) {
    ...
}
```

That loop will *not* terminate whenever `flag` becomes false. It terminates when it *tests* `flag` and finds it to be false. That only happens once each time around the loop. You could write the loop like this instead, and it would behave in exactly the same way:

```
while (true) {
    if (! flag) break;
    ...
}
```

So if you have this,

```
while (flag) {
    ...executeFizz.await()...
}
```

And if the `flag` changes from true to false while the thread is stuck in the `await()` call, then the loop won't terminate until *after* the `await()` call returns...

...that will never happen in your example because after the `for` loop has counted up to `n`, it sets `flag=false;` but it does *not* signal any of the other waiting threads.

---

> @SolomonSlow i tried signalling all 3, but no luck
>   after adding if condition, at the end of the code I included this code...

My guess is, it's because there is no call to `lock.unlock()` anywhere in your program.  Here's what probably happens:

1. Three "worker" threads are all in calls to `executeXxxxx.await()` (each awaiting its own condition variable.)
2. The "main" thread reaches the end of the loop (It currently is the owner of the `lock`,) and it signals each of the `executeXxxxxx` condition variables.
3. The "main" thread ends, but the `lock` still is locked.  All three of the "worker" threads now have been released from awaiting their respective conditions, but their `await()` calls can not return until the lock becomes available.
4. The lock never will become available because there's no running thread that can unlock it.

You need to have every thread call `lock.unlock()` before it ends.

Comment: after adding if condition, at the end of the code I included this code ```flag = false;
     executeFizzBuzz.signal();
  executeFizz.signal();
  executeBuzz.signal();```

not working

Comment: yes by calling lock.unlock it worked, don't no but I have read somewhere that call to await automatically unlocks the lock.

Comment: @Shelly, `cond.await()` unlocks the associated lock on entry, and then it re-locks the lock before it returns. None of the printing threads could return from their `executeXxxxx.await()` calls because they were all waiting their turn to re-lock `lock`. The reason they waited forever is because the last thread to own the lock, the main thread, terminated itself without ever unlocking it.